# How to recognize the view.cshtml that you are coming from using ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 views:

lista.cshtml

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Eliminar","Productos", new {id = @item.Id})" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
```

cuadricula.cshtml

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Eliminar","Productos", new {id = @Model.Producto.Id})"  class="btn btn-danger" hidden="@Model.Modificar" >
    Eliminar Producto
</a>
```

They have the same action, but I want to differentiate them inside controller because I want to return different `return RedirectToAction();`

Eliminar

```
public IActionResult Eliminar(int? id)
{
        // .. rest of the code

        if(you are coming from lista.chtml)
        {
           return RedirectToAction("return_1");
        }
        else if(you are coming from cradicula.cshtml)
        {
           return RedirectToAction("return_2");
        }
        //.. so on
}
```

How can I achieve this? The only solution to this is to create another `Eliminar` Controller of each different view but I would be violating DRY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a second parameter to the Eliminar method which you can populate with a value indicating where the redirect should go to.

e.g.

```
public IActionResult Eliminar(int? id, string redirectTo)
```

and

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Eliminar","Productos", new {id = @item.Id, redirectTo = "lista"})" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
```

Hopefully the rest is obvious.